# 404 Error on #2 visited on my site! What are they?

Tags: google-analytics

When checking out my page on Google Analytics, I didn't recognize the 2nd most visited page of my site. When I clicked on it, it just goes to a Page 404 Error. What is this page? Where did it come from, and How are Sooo many people getting routed to it? You'll also see my 4th visited page has the same issue! Please help!

[PIC HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwMds.jpg)

Comment: Can you check the hostname and see if it is even on the same domain?
Also I think your website is double counting. Should get it fixed so you can get accurate results.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/